# How to use JSON data to populate a d3 chart (highcharts)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

```js
var units = {
                    title: 'override'
                };
                var optionsPie = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'existingOrNew-chart',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'new'
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y + ' ' + units.title+Math.round(this.percentage*100)/100 + ' %';
                           
                        }
                    },
                     credits: {
    enabled: false
},
                    exporting: { enabled: false },
                    series: []
                };

                $(document).ready(function() {                                                          
                    $.get('csvFiles/ExistingNew.csv', function(data) {
                        var seriesPie = {
                            data: []
                        };
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(obj.Sheet6);
                        
                        var seriesPieItem = new Array();
                  
                        var lines = data.split('\n');
                        console.log(lines);

                        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                            var items = line.split(',');
                            if (lineNo == 0) {
                                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item)
                                {
                                    if (itemNo == 0) optionsPie.title.text = item;
                                    if (itemNo == items.length - 1) units.title = item; 
                                });
                            }
                          
                            else
                            {
                                seriesPieItem = new Array();                                
                                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item)
                                {
                                    if (itemNo == 0)
                                    {
                                        seriesPieItem.push(item);                                       
                                    } 
                                    else
                                    {
                                        seriesPieItem.push(parseFloat(item));                                        
                                    }
                                });                               
                                seriesPie.data.push(seriesPieItem);
                            }
                        }); 

                        optionsPie.series.push(seriesPie);
                        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsPie);
                    });                   
                });
```

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class="my-3 mx-auto">
          <div class="card" style="position: relative; width: 60vw;">
            <div class="card-title text-center">
                <h4><b>Existing or New Customer</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="existingOrNew-chart"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

This d3 chart is from highcharts. I used a csv file's data to populate this chart.
And I have this json Data:

```
{
    "Sheet6": [
            {
                "RowLabels": "Existing",
                "CountOfClientName": 21
            },
            {
                "RowLabels": "New",
                "CountOfClientName": 28
            }
        ]
}
```

Now I have included a new feature that is uploading an xlsx file. But first I have to convert the xlsx file data into json data and use that in the chart. I made the conversion and I got the Json data above .How can I use the  "Sheet6" data in the chart. Instead of using the csv file data, is it possible to use the json data("Sheet6") in the chart?.  Can you please help me. Thank You

Comment: The JSON data doesn't look valid?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry, I missed the brackets